# filtering fields of an inlineformset_factory

Tags: python, django

I have these models:

```
class TourItem(models.Model):
   Tour=models.ForeignKey(Tour)
   TourItemType=models.ForeignKey(TourItemType)
   Transfer=models.ForeignKey(Transfer)
   Accommodate=models.ForeignKey(Accommodate)
   Visit=models.ForeignKey(Visit)
```

and:

```
class Tour(models.Model):
   Lang_Choices=(
      ('fa',ugettext_lazy('Persian')),
      ('en',ugettext_lazy('English')),
      ('fr',ugettext_lazy('French')),
   )
   Lang=models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=Lang_Choices,editable=False)
   Name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Description=models.TextField()
   ActionDate=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,editable=False)
```

and this inlineformset:

```
TourItemFormSet=inlineformset_factory(Tour,TourItem,can_delete=True,extra=4)
```

Accommodate,TourItemType,Transfer and Visit Models have a field named Lang,when I make formset I have 4 comboboxes for these models in each form,now I wanna filter these comboboxes with `request.LANGUAGE_CODE` .I searched a lot and ended up with this code:

```
def get_field_qs(field, **kwargs):
      if field.name == 'TourItemType':
     field.queryset = TourItemType.objects.filter(Lang__iexact=request.LANGUAGE_CODE)
      return field
   TourItemFormSet=inlineformset_factory(Tour,TourItem,formfield_callback=get_field_qs,can_delete=True,extra=4)
```

but now It shows no field,how can I handle this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this from within your **view**:

```
TourItemFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Tour,TourItem,can_delete=True,extra=4)
TourItemFormSet.form.base_fields["TourItemType"].queryset = TourItemType.objects.filter(Lang__iexact=request.LANGUAGE_CODE)
# then create an instance of TourItemFormSet and add to template context
```